# The named parameter 'selectedOption' is required, but there's no corresponding argument. Required named parameter 'selectedOption' must be provided

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, dart-null-safety

I am getting "The named parameter 'selectedOption' is required, but there's no corresponding argument error" in flutter. I tried some things but it did not work. There are some other questions as well but I copied just 2 of them to show the error.It seems like I need to add selectedoption key for some reason.Could you help?

[image]

```
final questions = [
  Question(
    text: 'Which planet is the hottest in the solar system?',
    options: [
      Option(code: 'A', text: 'Earth', isCorrect: false),
      Option(code: 'B', text: 'Venus', isCorrect: true),
      Option(code: 'C', text: 'Jupiter', isCorrect: false),
      Option(code: 'D', text: 'Saturn', isCorrect: false),
    ],
    solution: 'Venus is the hottest planet in the solar system',
  ),
  Question(
    text: 'How many molecules of oxygen does ozone have?',
    options: [
      Option(code: 'A', text: '1', isCorrect: false),
      Option(code: 'B', text: '2', isCorrect: false),
      Option(code: 'C', text: '5', isCorrect: false),
      Option(code: 'D', text: '3', isCorrect: true),
    ],
    solution: 'Ozone have 3 molecules of oxygen',
  ),
];

class OptionsWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Question question;
  final ValueChanged<Option> onClickedOption;

  const OptionsWidget({
    required this.question,
    required this.onClickedOption,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ListView(
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        children: Utils.heightBetween(
          question.options
              .map((option) => buildOption(context, option))
              .toList(),
          height: 8,
        ),
      );

      Widget buildOption(BuildContext context, Option option) {
        final color = getColorForOption(option, question);
    
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => onClickedOption(option),
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: color,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                buildAnswer(option),
                buildSolution(question.selectedOption, option),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Widget buildAnswer(Option option) => Container(
            height: 50,
            child: Row(children: [
              Text(
                option.code,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 24),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 12),
              Text(
                option.text,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              )
            ]),
          );
    
      Widget buildSolution(Option solution, Option answer) {
        if (solution == answer) {
          return Text(
            question.solution,
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          );
        } else {
          return Container();
        }
      }
    
      Color getColorForOption(Option option, Question question) {
        final isSelected = option == question.selectedOption;
    
        if (!isSelected) {
          return Colors.grey.shade200;
        } else {
          return option.isCorrect ? Colors.green : Colors.red;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Add your Question object

Comment: Click on the `Add required parameter` link in that popup (or Alt+Shift+Enter) and it will autofix it for you! The error message couldn't be clearer: just pass an argument with that name to the function like `Question(selectedOption: 'foo', ...)`.